# RequireJS executing file code before dependencies are loaded/resolved

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require, requirejs, amd

Requirejs seems to be allowing rels.js to run before Rel is loaded. https://github.com/yedi/Avalon/blob/backbone_rewrite/avalon/static/app/modules/collections/rels.js
So Rel is undefined when I debug for it inside the initialize() function. model is also not being defined because Rel isn't defined.

I can't seem to understand why this is happening. Other files that are requiring the same Rel model don't seem to have this issue. (in both https://github.com/yedi/Avalon/blob/backbone_rewrite/avalon/static/app/modules/views/node.js and https://github.com/yedi/Avalon/blob/backbone_rewrite/avalon/static/app/modules/views/child.js, Rel is defined when I debug it. I require Rel the exact same way that I do inside rels.js)

I'm having this same issue with my items.js collection.

Any help/suggestions on how I can debug this problem? (I have no idea how I would even tackle it and I've been banging my head on this problem for a few days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have a circular dependency.
Your [collection](https://github.com/yedi/Avalon/blob/backbone_rewrite/avalon/static/app/modules/collections/rels.js) requires the [child](https://github.com/yedi/Avalon/blob/backbone_rewrite/avalon/static/app/modules/models/rel.js) model and vice-versa. Kill the `"modules/collections/rels"` requirement in the child model, it should not need to know how it will be contained in a collection.